# How to map a complex multi-key combination into a shortcut to execute a process, in X (across WMs etc)?

Tags: xorg, keyboard-shortcuts

I am wondering how can I make a complex multi-key combination like say, Ctrl+Alt+T into a shortcut to execute me a process,`xterm` for instance? **The important caveat is that I want it wired into either X itself or at an even lower level of abstraction**. The reason is that I want it to work across display- and window managers, desktop environments and their own input event stacks, also because I don't want to customize each and any of them to produce the same behavior.

I have noticed there are a lot of questions pertaining to input in UNIX/X but most of them deal with remapping/fixing single exotic keys or I end up with `xbindkeys` tool. Am I really left with no other choice? No `XkbOptions` wizardry to the rescue? Or `.Xresources` maybe?

I'll repeat again - I know of countless ways to actually do what I ask for in say GNOME or OpenBox, but I have gotten tired of learning new tricks for the same old thing, and in particular of having to duplicate the behavior with different mechanisms. Ideally, this would be something X can do alone.

Comment: Why not xbindkeys? That's exactly its job.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. It does the job alright ;-) But somehow I still have the feeling that X is missing a better keyboard protocol extension - one that can deal with multi-key combinations without one ending up with another daemon. That said `xbindkeys` is great, I am planning to extend it to support shared library calls.

Comment: @Gilles Exactly - I think you should add this as an answer.